# Como ejecutar en archivo bat un comando de PowerShell

Tags: cmd, batch, powershell

Tengo un codigo en PowerShell que funciona correctamente, hace lo que deseo.
Deseo ponerlo en .bat , pero cuando lo ejecuto como .bat no realiza nada.
Soy totalmente nuevo en programacion en PowerShell/cmd

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
Get-ChildItem 'Z:\Caterpillar\Cesar\TerrainTest\Input\*.*' -Recurse | ForEach {
(Get-Content $_ | ForEach { $_ -replace 'P,D', 'P,D,' }) |
Set-Content $_
}
```

Que basicamente busca: 'P,D' en todos los archivos de una ruta y los cambia por 'P,D,'

Answer (score 0):

Crea un archivo `.bat` que llame y ejecute tu archivo `.ps1`

En tu archivo **.bat** : deberá ir lo siguiente:

```
@echo off
@powershell -noninteractive -nologo -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -command "Aquí pon la ruta de tu archivo powershell"
```